# Oracle Linux 7 mounting SAN storage issue

Tags: linux, mount, storage, oracle, san

I have a scenario where I am trying to mount SAN storage to my linux machine. My environment details are-

1. Oracle VM manager for VM creation
2. Fiber Channel HP3PAR SAN storage attached as physical disk to my VM
3. Oracle Linux version -OEL 7.4

Below steps I have been doing as earlier worked smoothly but not now-

1. Login as root user on VM Running
2. fdisk utility to check attached disks

   fdisk -l

   It shows 2 disks /dev/xvdb & /dev/xvdc where /dev/xvdc appeared after attaching the SAN storage to VM.
3. Applying mount command to mount /dec/xvdc on location
   /u01/oracle/config where /u01/oracle/config is empty

   mount /dev/xvdc /u01/oracle/config
4. After this the command screen cursor just blinks and nothing
   happens.
   Further I have checked whether the mount was successful, no it is not. Running the command 'df -h' and 'mount' doesn't shows the storage was mounted to requested location.

[image: Storage attached but not able to mount]

Comment: Syslog is where you should look at for error messages (like I/O timeouts).  
Also it looks as if you are running in a Xen Paravirtualized machine using disks imported from the Xen host (/dev/xvd*). If so, you should look at the Xen host...  
Anyway you should describe your scenario better.

Comment: `mount` also has a `--verbose` option that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The issue was associated with disk log corruption. 
So I tried to repair the disk using below steps-

```
xfs_repair /dev/xvdc
```

a warning indicated as specified below

Phase 1 - find and verify superblock...

Phase 2 - using internal log

```
    - zero log...
```

ERROR: The filesystem has valuable metadata changes in a log which needs to
be replayed.  Mount the filesystem to replay the log, and unmount it before
re-running xfs_repair.  If you are unable to mount the filesystem, then use
the -L option to destroy the log and attempt a repair.
Note that destroying the log may cause corruption -- please attempt a mount
of the filesystem before doing this.

**So further, I proceeded with below steps-**

```
xfs_repair -L /dev/xvdc 

mount -t xfs /dev/xvdc /u01/oracle
```

This successfully mount disk /dev/xvdc to location /u01/oracle.

**NOTE :** I have formatted the disk using XFS file system earlier.